# eBay OAuth Authorize Grant Flow Invalid Parameters

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I'm using the ebay-oauth-java-client to get an authorization url, however, this seems to not be working and complaining
**Error message:**

```
{"error_id":"invalid_request","error_description":"Input request parameters are invalid.","http_status_code":400}
```

auth url with client secret added to end:

```
https://auth.sandbox.ebay.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=blabla-blabla-blabla-blabla-blabla&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/callback&scope=https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.order.readonly&state=randomString&client_secret=blabla-blablabla
```

Code:

```
        OAuth2Api oauth2Api = new OAuth2Api();
        String state = "randomString"; // Optional state parameter for CSRF protection
        String authorizationUrl = oauth2Api.generateUserAuthorizationUrl(Environment.SANDBOX, SCOPES, Optional.of(state));
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND)
                .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, authorizationUrl))
                .build());
```

Any ideas as to what i could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Redirect uri isn't really a uri, it expects a ebay RuName id:
in the case below mine is Jaime_Moncayo-blabalablabla

[image]

therefore the authlink would be `https://auth.sandbox.ebay.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=blabla-blabla-blabla-blabla-blabla&response_type=code&redirect_uri=jaime_moncayo-balbla&scope=https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.order.readonly&state=randomString&client_secret=blabla-blablabla`